# How to convert an observable list to an array list? Java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get all the items in a table view and place them in an array list for further processing. This is what I'm trying to achieve but obviously it won't work.

```
ArrayList<Consultation> showing = consultationTable.getItems();
```

Comment: If you _must_ have an `ArrayList`, then `ArrayList<Consultation> showing = new ArrayList<Consultation>(consultationTable.getItems())`

Comment: what about ``ArrayList<Consultation> showing = new ArrayList<>(consultationTable.getItems());`` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why specifically need an `ArrayList`? Why not `List<Consultation> showing = ...;`? Program to an interface, not an implementation.

Comment: Since both `ObservableList` and `ArrayList` are `List` implementations, maybe you don't really need to do this conversion at all?  The code line you show us is stylistically flawed because you are showing us a variable declared with its implementation type (ArrayList) when a perfectly good interface type is available (List).

Comment: Why on earth do you need that? Unless you went out of your way to do otherwise, the `ObservableList` is backed by an `ArrayList` anyway (the default way to create one is `ObservableList<Consultation> obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` or similar.). So what is wrong with `List<Consultation> showing = consultationTable.getItems();`. Is there really some `ArrayList`-specific API you need?

Comment: Thanks khelwood and f1sh, that worked. Needed it because a parameter for a method in another class is asking for an ArrayList of Consultations, specifically

Comment: Philayyy, can you modify that other class? Perhaps just changing the parameter type would work.

Comment: I wish that was the case, I didn't own the other class another developer created it and was using it for a database method. Too much would need to be changed on his end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice and recommended solution:

```
List<Consultation> showing = provider.getItems();
```

Solution to use only if necessary:

```
    List<Consultation> consultations = provider.getItems();
    ArrayList<Consultation> showing;
    if (consultations instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
        showing = (ArrayList<Consultation>) consultations;
    } else {
        showing = new ArrayList<>(consultations);
    }
```

If for some reason you need to use an ArrayList method that is not in the List or ObservableList interface (I cannot readily think of why), you may use the latter.

Answer (score 6):

A simple method using Stream class

```
List<T> list = ObservableList<T>.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
new ArrayList<>(consultationTable.getItems())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// To convert an observable list to an array of strings given the following observable list:

// Create these in the class 
ListView<String> myListView = new ListView<>();
ObservableList<String> myList;
```

// Then define them in the start class 
   myList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(someGivenArray);
   myListView.setItems(myList);

```
// Make an array to store list items in the observable list as strings
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

// Loop through the observable list and load the string array
    for (int i =0; i<myList.size(); i++){
       myArray.add(myList.get(i));
    }
// Test by printing out to the screen or a text field
    System.out.println(myList.get(0));
    myTextField.setText(myList.get(0));
```

Comment: `ObservableList` *is* a `List`. Elements can be added from one list to another at construction time or using the `addAll` method.